# TTS doesn't speak from a service whereas it does it from an activity in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have been able to run TTS from an activity but when I try to execute the same code from a service, it's giving me message that TTS engine is initialised but not speaking anything.

Has anybody encountered the same issue anytime?

```
 public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this //TextToSpeech.OnInitListener);

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask()                       
    {                                   // In timer

          public void run() {
          //On some condition
          tts.speak("thank you", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
     }, 0, 60000);
    }

  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {  
  if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
  Toast.makeText(BackgroundProcessforTimecheck.this, 
  "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
  Toast.makeText(BackgroundProcessforTimecheck.this, 
  "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet used in Service.?

Comment: which version of android you are using?

Comment: tts.speak("thank you", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); - add to onInit(...) method. Maybe TTS hasn't yet started

Comment: In init, it speaks Thank you. But from inside my timer task, it fails to speak.

Comment: Don't see any problem with the timer, Did you wait for 60 sec to confirm tts is not working.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:
Instantiate TextToSpeech Object in a separate Class (in my case I furthermore use a Factory to check if the Android Version is at least Donut) and **reuse it** (see method init(Context context)). Please notice that the onInit(int status) is far from being ready to release.

Service:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
Context context = getApplicationContext();
TtsProviderFactory ttsProviderImpl = TtsProviderFactory.getInstance();
if (ttsProviderImpl != null) {
    ttsProviderImpl.init(context);
    ttsProviderImpl.say("hope that helps);
}}
```

Factory:

```
public abstract class TtsProviderFactory {

public abstract void say(String sayThis);

public abstract void init(Context context);

public abstract void shutdown();


private static TtsProviderFactory sInstance;

public static TtsProviderFactory getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        int sdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
        if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            String className = "TtsProviderImpl";
            Class<? extends TtsProviderFactory> clazz =
                    Class.forName(TtsProviderFactory.class.getPackage().getName() + "." + className)
                            .asSubclass(TtsProviderFactory.class);
            sInstance = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}}
```

Implementation:

```
public class TtsProviderImpl extends TtsProviderFactory implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

private TextToSpeech tts;

public void init(Context context) {
    if (tts == null) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void say(String sayThis) {
    tts.speak(sayThis, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    Locale loc = new Locale("de", "", "");
    if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(loc) >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
        tts.setLanguage(loc);
    }
}

public void shutdown() {
    tts.shutdown();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the TTS engine in your device. I too faced the same problem with the same message. But later I found that I have to install the TTS engine to my real device also and it is available in the play store.